# Sand as cat litter

Tags: cats

I'm asking about sand as cat litter.

I'm looking into transitioning from Arm & Hammer cat litter to using sand.

There is a lot of different information on sand, so I thought I'd ask people with more experience.

1. Is it a good idea?
2. Are there any terrible cons other than the odor or tracking all over the house? (In which case does adding baking soda *actually* help?)
3. What type of sand would be best? The ones I've found are either
   White Stradbroke Sand, Fine River Sand, and/or Coarse River Sand.
4. Most of all, is it a good idea to do this with four cats? (I do have four litter boxes, all in a bedroom which is specifically for the cats.)

Cat litter is just so expensive now, and my personal preference is to change it every week. I currently use Arm & Hammer Multi-Cat Strength Clumping Litter. It's OK if a replacement doesn't clump.

I'm also wanting to transition to something of this sort because of allergies. I'm allergic to dust mites and my current litter doesn't help. I'm not well off enough to spend more than what I am right now for a different litter, hence me asking all these questions!

Comment: You might be asking the wrong question. If you need to dump a heap of *mostly clean* cat litter each week, try a higher quality clumping litter. Yes, it is more expensive, but if you're careful while scooping out the clumps, you don't have to throw away any of the unclumped litter. I use "Premiere" brand litter from a pet store, not the stuff you get at the supermarket. It costs roughly 1€ per kilogram and the clumps don't fall apart. I haven't had to completely empty the litter box for 3 months now.

Comment: Seconding @Elmy 's comments, using a better litter, or simply not throwing it all out every week, can make a huge difference. I currently have three cats primarily using one box (their choice, they ignore the other ones). I use a lighter corn-based litter, $18 for 15 lbs, which lasts at two weeks before I need to buy another bag, and only needs a full replacement every 3-4 bags. (Note it is *much lighter* than clay, so do not compare weight, but timeline.)